# MDX LAG Command in Calculated Measure return wrong value

Tags: ssas, mdx, measure

I have following query

> ```
> with member priorSellOut as
>   ([Date].[Year Month].CurrentMember.LAG(1),MEASURES.[Sell Out])
> Select 
>   {
>       MEASURES.[Sell Out]
>       ,PriorSellOut
>   } ON COLUMNS,
>   [Date].[Year Month].[Year Month].Members ON ROWS
> From Sales
> ```

the result of this query is:

> ```
>              Sell Out       Prior Sell Out
>    2018.01   34329          (null)
>    2018.02   37752          34329
>    2018.03   21798          37752
>    2018.04   41477          21798
>    2018.05   50125          41477
>    2018.06   6363           50125
>    2018.07   11511          6363
>    2018.08   7444           11511
>    2018.09   13989          7444
>    2018.10   1936           13989
> ```

I want to have last 3 month ago. and use **[3 Month Ago]** named set.following query:

> ```
> with member priorSellOut as
>   ([Date].[Year Month].CurrentMember.LAG(1),MEASURES.[Sell Out])
> Select 
>   {
>       MEASURES.[Sell Out]
>       ,PriorSellOut
>   } ON COLUMNS,
>   [Date].[Year Month].[Year Month].Members ON ROWS
> From Sales
> Where ([3 Month Ago])
> ```

the result of this query is:

> ```
>              Sell Out       Prior Sell Out
>    2018.08   7444           (null)
>    2018.09   13989          7444
>    2018.10   1936           13989
> ```

I want to have following result. Prior Sell Out Column for 2018.08 must have value.

> ```
>              Sell Out       Prior Sell Out
>    2018.08   7444           11511
>    2018.09   13989          7444
>    2018.10   1936           13989
> ```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that instead of filtering on the list of rows to display, you instead filter out all data that is not in the last 3 months.

To filter out the rows - just apply a limited set expression to the axis. We want the last 3 months to be displayed, so let's take the last three members of the months list like so: *TAIL([Date].[Year Month].[Year Month].Members,3)* . Now we can safely remove the WHERE clause. The result is:

```
with member priorSellOut as
  ([Date].[Year Month].CurrentMember.LAG(1),MEASURES.[Sell Out])
Select 
  {
      MEASURES.[Sell Out]
      ,PriorSellOut
  } ON COLUMNS,
  TAIL([Date].[Year Month].[Year Month].Members,3) ON ROWS
From Sales
```

NOTE: This assumes that the [Date].[Year Month].[Year Month] dimension IS PROPERLY ORDERED

EDIT: If you really necessary need to use the [3 Month Ago] named set - just put it on the axis instead of the TAIL(...) formula I used.